# Kubuntu returns to sleep after wake

Tags: 14.04, suspend

I have a Dell Latitude E5420M running Kubuntu 13.04 (now 14.04). I have it set to suspend to RAM whenever it detects a lid close. Quite often, whenever I wake it up (lid open), the computer stays active for 5-10 seconds (fully operational) and then returns to sleep without me closing the lid. I can wake it up afterward, at which point it functions normally.

I have turned the Internet inside out trying to find a solution to this, but I have found absolutely nothing.

I have noticed this behavior with Kubuntu 12.04 LTS as well (before I got a new hard drive), although it did not happen as often.

**Edit**: I recently updated to 14.04, but I still experience this behavior.

Comment: I recently updated to 14.04, but I still experience this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

uncomment the line `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` and change the value to `ignore`

This work for me.

Comment: Okay... but this breaks lid close actions. Note that I still need the computer to sleep after the lid closes. The problem I am having is that it goes back to sleep after I wake it up without me closing the lid.

Comment: It still goes to sleep for me. Have you make sure that the setting is set to sleep under power management settings?

Comment: Yes, it is set to sleep on lid close.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I tested this solution. It seems that it works, but I have to test it further.